# onTrigger method of triggereventlistner is not called even after significant motion in android

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors, significant-motion-sensor

An significant motion sensor is registered with triggereventlistener using requestTriggerSensor method of sensormanager.

The onTrigger method of the triggereventlistener is called only once and after sometime even when there is significant motion the ontrigger method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Autually there is issue in the sensor and as it is providing the callback.
The issue is with sensor not with android app.